# Array to google charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to pass an array of numbers to a google charts, that array is being pulled by this code from a div with a class .likescount

```
var i, $mvar = $('.likescount'); // using the $ prefix to use the "jQuery wrapped var" convention

function logit( string )
{
    var text = document.createTextNode( string );
    $('.alllikesinrow').append(text);
    $('.alllikesinrow').append("<br>");
}

logit($mvar.length);

for (i=0; i<$mvar.length; i++)    {
    logit($mvar.eq(i).html());
}
```

The array is working because im using the append to print it and its working, the hard part is to pass that data to data.addRows, heres the full code i'm using, worked around it, but never got it worked, i'm following this guy that got it working [how to add data in google charts using javascript ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34904482/how-to-add-data-in-google-charts-using-javascript) , but without luck, any help wold be great.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


function drawChart() {

    var i, $mvar = $('.likescount'); // using the $ prefix to use the "jQuery wrapped var" convention

    x = [];

    for (i=0; i<$mvar.length; i++ )    {

        x.push( ['1', parseFloat($($mvar[i]).text())] );
    }


  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Day');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Likes');

  data.addRows(x);

  var options = {
    chart: {
      title: 'Likes vs Comentarios',
      subtitle: 'Data Magnus by Optimum'
    },

    height: 500
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

  chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options), {pointSize: 1});
}
</script>
```

Thanks Rodrigo

**EDIT:** Edited with a working push thanks to **WhiteHat**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addRows` takes an array of arrays, which is what you are building here...

```
x = [];

for (i=0; i<$mvar.length; i++)    {
    logit($mvar.eq(i).html());
    x.push( ['August', $mvar[i]] );
}
```

as such, simply use `x` for `addRows`...

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Day');
data.addColumn('number', 'Likes');

data.addRows(x);
```

**EDIT**

not sure what `$('.likescount')` contains,
but if each is an element with a number, then try...

```
x.push( ['August', parseFloat($($mvar[i]).text())] );
```

Comment: thanks for the info, you got right data.addRows(x); , thanks for that, im having trouble is with this string x.push( ['August', $mvar[i]] ); the $mvar[i] isnt the right variable for that push, im still not getting data. any extra help would be nice thanks.

Comment: Thanks man great answer, I wanna ask you another thing, i wanna render more colums with the push, but im not good for programming, i did this but it was wrong

var i, $mvar = $('.likescount'); 
        var b, $mvarcom = $('.comcount');

        x = [];

        for (i=0; i<$mvar.length; i++; b=0; b<$mvarcom.length; b++)    {
            
            x.push( ['1', parseFloat($($mvar[i]).text()), parseFloat($($mvarcom[b]).text())] );
        }

Comment: for something like that to work, `$mvar` and `$mvarcom` would need to have the same number of elements, if so --> `var i, $mvar = $('.likescount'); var b, $mvarcom = $('.comcount'); x = []; for (i=0; i<$mvar.length; i++;) { x.push( ['1', parseFloat($($mvar[i]).text()), parseFloat($($mvarcom[i]).text())] ); }`

Comment: Just got time, to say thanks you, worked great. :D
Cheers mate

Answer (score 1):

try using **google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(array)**

the array contains an array of the row values to be displayed in the chart