# How can I use a Array to make a scatter chart from google?

Tags: jquery, charts, google-visualization

I have some problems with creating a chart because of the "type" of the array, for example in `var data = ...` in the examples they use `[12, 30], [14, 98]` but I wanted to use a array defined like I have in the code for these values and I dont know how I can to that.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready!");

  ko.applyBindings(new vm());

  var k = 0;
  var Arraydata1 = [];
  var Arraydata2 = [];

  console.log(indice)
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://192.168.160.58/Formula1/api/Statistics/Driver?id=' + indice,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      for (k = 0; k < data.Career.length; k++) {

        Arraydata1.push(data.Career[k].Year);
        Arraydata2.push(data.Career[k].Position);

      }
      drawChart(Arraydata1, Arraydata2)
    },
  });

});

function drawChart(Arraydata1, Arraydata2) {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Price', 'Size'],
    // dont know what to put here
  ]);
  // Set Options
  var options = {
    title: 'House Prices vs. Size',
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Square Meters'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Price in Millions'
    },
    legend: 'none'
  };
  // Draw
  var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('myChart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: will you please share a sample of the data you want to use?

Comment: Please 1. add HTML and CDN of the chart plugin and 2. Change `$.ajax({url: 'http://192.168.160.58/Formula1/api/Statistics/Driver?id=' + indice,contentType: "application/json",dataType: 'json',success: function(data) {for (k = 0; k < data.Career.length; k++) { Arraydata1.push(data.Career[k].Year); Arraydata2.push(data.Career[k].Position);} drawChart(Arraydata1, Arraydata2)},` to 
just your data and `function(data) { for (k = 0; k < data.Career.length; k++) {Arraydata1.push(data.Career[k].Year);Arraydata2.push(data.Career[k].Position);}` plus `drawChart(Arraydata1, Arraydata2)`

Comment: And why do you not want to use the format they use? It is easier to create the arrays using their format than to convert whatever format you create to their format

Comment: Example of data'[2000. 1], [2001. 2], ... [2010, 11]'. but this will change depending the driver i choose so i use the arrays Arraydata1 and Arraydata2. @WhiteHat and for mplungjan

Comment: @WhiteHat I saw a reply you did in another question that is a little like the same question ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45668415/array-to-google-charts)). I tried to follow but it didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

combine the row values from `Career` into a single array -- `Arraydata`

```
Arraydata.push([data.Career[k].Year, data.Career[k].Position]);
```

pass that array to draw chart

```
drawChart(Arraydata);
```

then create the data table with the necessary column headings,
and use the `addRows` method.

```
// create data table
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('number', 'Price');
data.addColumn('number', 'Size');
data.addRows(Arraydata);
```

see following snippet...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready!");

  ko.applyBindings(new vm());

  var k = 0;
  var Arraydata = [];

  console.log(indice)
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://192.168.160.58/Formula1/api/Statistics/Driver?id=' + indice,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      for (k = 0; k < data.Career.length; k++) {

        Arraydata.push([data.Career[k].Year, data.Career[k].Position]);

      }
      drawChart(Arraydata);
    },
  });

});

function drawChart(Arraydata) {
  // create data table
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'Price');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Size');
  data.addRows(Arraydata);

  // Set Options
  var options = {
    title: 'House Prices vs. Size',
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Square Meters'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Price in Millions'
    },
    legend: 'none'
  };
  // Draw
  var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('myChart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, now it works thx. Sorry this was basicly the same u did for the other one, i was dumb xD

Comment: no worries, don't beat yourself up, sometimes it can be hard to translate to your own code. just glad to help...